# system halt twice a week

Tags: linux, centos

My system stop responding almost twice a week. following message is found in log,

```
Apr 27 04:44:37 Helpdesk shutdown[29686]: shutting down for system halt
Apr 27 04:44:39 Helpdesk modclusterd: shutdown succeeded
Apr 27 04:44:41 Helpdesk ricci: shutdown succeeded
Apr 27 04:44:41 Helpdesk smartd[4102]: smartd received signal 15: Terminated
Apr 27 04:44:41 Helpdesk smartd[4102]: smartd is exiting (exit status 0)
Apr 27 04:44:41 Helpdesk avahi-daemon[3618]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Apr 27 04:44:41 Helpdesk avahi-daemon[3618]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::21a:64ff:fec7:6f0.
Apr 27 04:44:41 Helpdesk avahi-daemon[3618]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 203.215.160.6.
Apr 27 04:44:41 Helpdesk oddjobd: oddjobd shutdown succeeded
```

can anyone please help?

Comment: Go find the person who turned off the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the cluster log, the service may have been fenced through iLO (and with acpid daemon running it becomes a clean shutdown).

Why do I think this? Is because you run ricci which is a cluster service, so it can be the case that your node gets fenced.